# What is the difference between というのは or は when used as a topical marker?

Tags: grammar, particle-って

> 旅館の朝食って おいしいですよね

**Context**:

The speaker and his friends (whom are all Japanese) were on a trip to a Japanese Inn, arriving at night. The next day, they woke up to have breakfast.

(This was probably the first meal they had at the inn as they went to sleep right away upon arriving at the inn last night. However, I doubt this was their first time in a Japanese Inn, seeing that they are all Japanese.)

**My questions:**

In this given sentence, how can I differentiate whether というのは or は should be used? I heard context is important, but what kind of clues can I gather from the context to determine which of the two is more appropriate. In this case, both というのは and　は seems to make sense to me.

The って in this case is used to describe how delicious is the inn's breakfast.

For は, the meaning is something like "As for the inn's breakfast, it is delicious".

For というのは, the meaning is something like "The thing about the inn's breakfast, it is delicious".

Are my interpretations right?

I browsed through several threads and managed to make some form of segregation of meanings between the different って usages, but am still confounded between these two.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think all three particles are acceptable. As for their difference, think of it this way:

These particles add some spotlights to the noun phrase that they are decorating. The only real differene here are how much spotlights they are adding: というのは > って > は.

って is a little informal, speech-oriented form. My guess is that either 旅館の朝食 was not mentioned prior to this point, in which case the added spotlight is used to signal the change of the subject, or the speaker is simply delighted with 旅館の朝食 and wanted to add an underscore.