# What does the って mean here?

Tags: grammar, particle-って

> 女: 先輩、来週、海外出張なんですが、特にしておいたほうがいいこと**って**、ありますか。

I read somewhere on this site って can mean と言ってる. Is this correct translation/thinking?

Senpai, next week, since we have the overseas business trip, is there anything I should prepare for you have been saying?

Next text for context:

男: 会議の資料は準備できてるんだよね。
女: はい。男:会社のパンフレット、持った?

Etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76909/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15004/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68660/9831

Comment: Note that it's not the "te-form" because こと is not a verb.

Comment: Okay so the meaning is that て can be interchangeable with は if I understand the linked posts correctly.